# propertyChangeListener doesn't detect JTree's change in preferred size when opening a folder

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, jtree

When opening a file in a `JTree`, the tree's preferred size changes but his `propertyChangeListener` doesn't detect it (but if you change it calling `setPreferredSize` is able to detect it). Is it my code that is wrong or is `javax.swing` bugged? If this isn't the way of doing this how should I do it. I tested the code with `maximumSize` as well.

Here is my code, you shouldn't need any external resources:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyJFrame()
    {
        add(new JTree()
        {
            {
                addPropertyChangeListener("preferredSize",
                new PropertyChangeListener()
                {
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
                    {
                        System.out.println("preferred size changed");
                    }
                });
                new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        while(true)
                        {
                            System.out.println("preferred size = "+getPreferredSize());
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyJFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: When calculated by the `JTree`, the `preferredSize` property is not actual set, it's just calculated, until you set it, then the value you provide is used instead of the calculated value, this may account for the fact that the property change event never triggers until you change the property yourself

Comment: 1) `PropertyChangeListener` Why is this even needed? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for a tree that requires no `PropertyChangeListener`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You are right, I didn't see that I can use `TreeExpansionListener` and I really thought `PropertyChangeListener` was the only solution to set the `JTree`'s minimum size equal to the preferred size.

Comment: If I wanted to set the minimum size equal to the preferred size I could also overwrite `getMinimumSize` to return `getPreferredSize`.